# Linear Programming Using Dual Simplex method

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I want to solve an optimization problem using the Dual Simplex Method. Although *Mathematica* gives the result directly when I use the command `Minimize` but I want to get the tableau results for every iterations.
How can I do that? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `LinearProgramming[]` is built-in; unfortunately, it does not give intermediate results.

Answer (score 5):

[image]You can use this. The code is not at all elegant but it works really well. It is designed to handle any number of variables and constraints. Just encode the constraints and the objective function, the objective function as the  last element of the array. It will automatically construct the simplex tableau, determine the pivot elements, reduce rows, until reaching the final tableau.

```
 Module[{A = {{1, 2, 3/2, 12000},
 {2/3, 2/3, 1, 4600},
 {1/2, 1/3, 1/2, 2400},
 {11, 16, 15, 0}}}, Atemp = {};
  constraints = Length[A] - 1;
  variables = Length[A[[1]]] - 1;
  A[[Length[A]]] = -A[[Length[A]]];
  c = Table[A[[i]][[variables + 1]], {i, 1, Length[A]}];

  echelon = Append[IdentityMatrix[constraints], Table[0, {i, 1, constraints}]];

  For[i = 0, i < Length[A], i++; A[[i]] = Drop[A[[i]], {variables + 1}]];
  For[i = 0, i < Length[A], i++;For[k = 0, k < constraints, k++;A[[i]] =Append[A[[i]],echelon[[i]][[k]]]]];

 (*Setting up the slack variables*)

 For[i = 0, i < Length[A], i++; A[[i]] = Append[A[[i]], c[[i]]]];vars = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, variables}];slack = Table[Subscript[s, i], {i, 1, constraints}];
 For[i = 0, i < Length[slack], i++;vars = Append[vars, slack[[i]]]];vars = Append[vars, "C"];

 Atemp = Append[Atemp, A];
(*Performing the Simplex Method*)
iteration = 1;
Subscript[pivot, iteration] = {};
While[Min[A[[Length[A]]]] < 0,Subscript[text, iteration] = {};

   (*Finding the Pivot column*)

   For[col = 0, col < Length[A] + 1, col++;
If[A[[Length[A]]][[col]] == Min[A[[Length[A]]]], Break[]]
];
 (*Finding the Pivot row*)

 cols = Table[A[[j]][[col]], {j, 1, constraints}];
  tem = Table[A[[k]][[Length[A[[1]]]]], {k, 1, Length[A] - 1}];
    If[Min[cols] <       0,For[i = 0, i < Length[cols], i++;If[cols[[i]] < 0 || cols[[i]] == 0,cols = ReplacePart[cols, i -> x]]],
If[Min[cols] == 0,For[i = 0, i < Length[cols], i++;If[cols[[i]] == 0, cols = ReplacePart[cols, i -> x]]]]];
     temp = Table[tem[[i]]/cols[[i]], {i, 1, Length[tem]}];
      If[Length[Min[temp]] > 1,For[row = 0, row < Length[temp], row++;If[temp[[row]] == Min[temp][[1]], Break[]]],For[row = 0, row < Length[temp], row++;If[temp[[row]] == Min[temp], Break[]]]];

  (*Performing Gaussian Elimination*)

 Subscript[text, iteration] = Append[Subscript[text, iteration],StringForm["R`` \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ``R``", row, If[A[[row]][[col]] == 0, 0, 1/A[[row]][[col]]], row]];

  If[A[[row]][[col]] == 0, A[[row]] = A[[row]],A[[row]] = A[[row]]/A[[row]][[col]]];For[j = 0, j < Length[A] - 1, j++;If[row + j < Length[A] + 1,
 Subscript[text, iteration] = 
  Append[Subscript[text, iteration], 
   StringForm["R`` \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ``R`` + R``", 
    row + j, -A[[row + j]][[col]], row, row + j]];
 A[[row + j]] = A[[row + j]] - A[[row + j]][[col]]*A[[row]],
 Subscript[text, iteration] = 
  Append[Subscript[text, iteration], 
   StringForm[
    "R`` \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ``R`` + R``", (row + j) - 
     Length[A], -A[[(row + j) - Length[A]]][[col]], 
    row, (row + j) - Length[A]]];
 A[[(row + j) - Length[A]]] = 
  A[[(row + j) - Length[A]]] - 
   A[[(row + j) - Length[A]]][[col]]*A[[row]]
 ]
];
   Subscript[pivot,iteration] = {"Pivot Element:", StringForm["col:`` ", col], 
 StringForm["row:`` ", row]};
  Atemp = Append[Atemp, A];
  iteration += 1;
 ];
    Subscript[text, iteration] = "";
    Subscript[pivot, iteration] = "";
  ];
      Manipulate[Column[{Style[TableForm[Atemp[[iteration]], TableHeadings -> {{""}, vars}],Large],Spacer[100],Row[{Column[{Subscript[pivot, iteration] // TableForm}],Spacer[100], Subscript[text, iteration] // TableForm}]},Alignment -> Center], {iteration, Table[n, {n, 1, Length[Atemp]}]}, ControlType -> SetterBar, ContentSize -> Automatic]
```

It can be easily altered to  perform minimization by inserting A=Transpose[A];

```
   Module[{A = {{1, 2, 3/2, 12000},
 {2/3, 2/3, 1, 4600},
 {1/2, 1/3, 1/2, 2400},
 {11, 16, 15, 0}}}, Atemp = {};
  A=Transpose[A];(*Insert Here*)
```

Comment: The code structure is not at all elegant but it works great. Just input the constraints and the objective function. The objective function is encoded as the last element of the array. It was designed to automatically construct and perform maximization. It can also be easily altered to perform minimization by inserting A = Transpose[A]; before constraints=Length[A]-1;

Comment: One should replace the `For`-loops by `Do`-loops and avoid `Subscript`.
`Subscript[pivot,iteration] = ...` does not do what you expect; have a look at `??Substript` after having executed the code.
Better use, e.g., `pivot[iteration] = ...` instead. Only then the result is stored in the symbol `pivot`.

Comment: Btw., it might be a good idea to color the pivot within the table.

Comment: Thanks man, your advice is much appreciated. I have been playing with mathematica for a few months and i really needed that. Been trying to add colors ffor the pivot but i am stuck.

Comment: You may use `Grid` instead of `TableForm`. Just browse its help page; you will find plenty of styling examples.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this, where you enter the tableau as an array and the pivot point you want to use for the current iteration.

```
reducesimplex[sim0_List, {pivRow_Integer, pivCol_Integer}] := 
  Module[{sim = sim0, piv = {pivRow, pivCol}}, 
    sim[[piv[[1]]]] = sim[[piv[[1]]]]/sim[[piv[[1]], piv[[2]]]];
    reducerows = Delete[Range[4], {piv[[1]]}];
    reducerows = DeleteCases[reducerows, Flatten@Position[Flatten[sim[[All, piv[[2]]]]], 0]];
    (sim[[#]] = -sim[[#, piv[[2]]]] sim[[piv[[1]]]] + sim[[#]]) & /@ reducerows;
    simplex = sim;
  ]
```

I have a very messy way of finding the pivot point for the next iteration if you need that as well.

(**Note**: This was made for 3 constraint variables and 3 slack variables only. Also, simplex tableau that is being inputted must be a feasible solution.)

```
findpivot[sim0_List] :=
  Module[{sim = sim0},
    enter = Flatten@Position[sim[[4, 1 ;; 6]], Min[DeleteCases[sim[[4, 1 ;; 6]], 0]]];
    ratios = Table[If[sim[[i, #]] != 0, sim[[i, 7]]/sim[[i, #]], Null], {i, 3}] & /@ enter;

    If[Flatten@Position[ratios, _?Negative] != {}, 
      If[Length[Position[ratiocheck, _?Negative]] >= 2, 
        ratiocheck = ratios; (ratiocheck[[#, #]] = Null) & /@ Position[ratiocheck, _?Negative], 
        ratiocheck = Flatten[Table[ratios, Length[Position[ratios, _?Negative]]], 1];
        (ratiocheck[[##]] = Null) & @@ Flatten@Position[ratiocheck, _?Negative];
        DeleteDuplicates[ratiocheck];],
      ratiocheck = ratios;];

    leastNonneg = Flatten@Position[ratiocheck, Min[ratiocheck /. {Null -> Nothing}]];

    If[leastNonneg == {}, 
      enter = Flatten@Position[sim[[4, 1 ;; 6]], 
      Min[DeleteCases[Drop[sim[[4, 1 ;; 6]], enter], 0]]];
      ratios = Table[If[sim[[i, #]] != 0, sim[[i, 7]]/sim[[i, #]], Null], {i,3}] & /@ enter;

      If[Flatten@Position[ratios, _?Negative] != {}, 
        If[Length[Position[ratiocheck, _?Negative]] >= 2, 
          ratiocheck = ratios; (ratiocheck[[#, #]] = Null) & /@ Position[ratiocheck, _?Negative], 
          ratiocheck = Flatten[Table[ratios, Length[Position[ratios, _?Negative]]], 1];
          (ratiocheck[[##]] = Null) & @@ Flatten@Position[ratiocheck, _?Negative]; 
          DeleteDuplicates[ratiocheck];     
        ],
        ratiocheck = ratios;];

    leastNonneg = Flatten@Position[ratiocheck, Min[ratiocheck /. {Null -> Nothing}]];
    ];

    pivot = {leastNonneg[[2]], enter[[leastNonneg[[1]]]]};
  ]
```

Like I said, messy, but it works as far as I have seen. There are much more concise ways of going about this I'm sure.