# Recover linear programming basis

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The `LinearProgramming` function solves a problem using the simplex method (by default). That means it internally selects a set of variables as basic (and the rest as nonbasic) to return the optimal solution (that is, it finds a basic feasible optimal solution). How do I retrieve this set? Please notice that this is not as simple as identifying nonzero variables in the solution, because there are so-called degenerate cases where some basic variables are zero. Also, (if it is not possible to directly retrieve the internally determined basis of `LinearProgramming`) please give a polynomial method. The immediately obvious 'trial-and-error' method is exponential.

PS: I saw another question on this site ([Linear programming pivot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/125117/27951)), but that one focuses on how to calculate the values of the variables given a set of variables as basis. This is the inverse problem.

Comment: Mauri, could you expand on what problem you are trying to solve more generally? Also, perhaps you could give a solvable small system and the related code for people to play with. It is in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for people to get involved in your question: a minimal working example with running code is perhaps the best way.

Comment: I'm using linear programming to find the sequential equilibria of a zero-sum two-player game using the method described [in this paper](http://www.itu.dk/~trbj/papers/seqeqsoda.pdf). It involves solving P_epsilon to find the _corresponding_ solution to P_delta by choosing the same set of basic variables.

Comment: "We simply run (...) LP solver on the program P_epsilon (...) The algorithm outputs (...) a partition of the variables into basic and non-basic ones, which enables us to find a symbolic description of the corresponding solution to P_delta as a polynomial in delta (...) and finally find the sequential equilibrium by setting delta = 0 in these symbolic expressions."

Comment: Also, see my essentially equivalent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751676/recover-linear-programming-basis) (but probably elaborated more clearly).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you were lucky. I guess that the function `` Optimization`LinearProgramming`LinearProgrammingSimplex `` is the backend used in the simplex method and it is not a `KernelFunction`. So we can make the code visible with `PrintDefinitions` from the `"GeneralUtilities`"` package like this:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[Optimization`LinearProgramming`LinearProgrammingSimplex]
```

Follow the hyperlinks to the function `` Optimization`LPSimplexDump`linearprogsimplex `` and the calls it makes. The function where the magic happens seems to be `` Optimization`LPSimplexDump`SimplexAlgorithm ``. There is a variable called `basics` and I guess that it might contain the indices of the current basis vectors.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to Mathematica... So does this mean that I can modify the `LinearProgramming` function so that it returns the `basics` variable?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to copy the existing code and to manipulate it in order to write a customized version, e.g., one that also returns `basics`. But I have to admit that this might be a bit too hard for a beginner. Moreover, I am not sure if the methods above are _really_ called by `LinearProgramming`. So quite a bit more reverse engineering would is necessary...